# ERROR: Value for /c option cannot be more than 253 characters (BATCH/CMD)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

so in my code below, I can't seem to get past the above error. I have tried to break out the command to multiple lines but then the %%I variable doesn't pass through. I've tried using normal for loops but that did not work either.

I've tried so many options but all to no avail. So please, how can i get past this annoying error?

CODE:

```
FORFILES /M *NTUSER.DAT /c "cmd /q /c for %%I in (@file) do (CD %RRIPPATH% & perl rip.pl -r %RRIPPATH%temp\%%~I -f ntuser>>%OUTPUT%\LiveResponseData\@file.txt)
```

I get... ERROR: Value for '/c' option cannot be more than 253 character(s)

Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, that is accurate.  There is a limit of 253 characters.   So?  Don't put in more than 253 characters. :)

Comment: I need more then 253 characters though, like way more. I've tried to trim down, but still over 253 :(

Comment: Then a single line batch-command is not for you.  You'll need a different format, or language.

Comment: ' FORFILES /M *NTUSER.DAT /c "cmd /q /c mybatch.bat @file' - put the whole `for` into `mybatch.bat`. Use `%1` to reference the parameter (instead of `@file`)

Comment: Break out the instructions after your `/c` into a batch file which accepts the value of `@file` as a parameter. Then call with `... /c DoThis.bat @file`

Comment: Unless there are more requirements not exposed in the question, the easiest way is *not to use `forfiles`*. Your code is not doing anything a simple `for` command could not handle.

Comment: @MCND I've tried doing a normal for command and it doesn't work. Could you please provide some insight into the for command, maybe I am messing up somewhere.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner I will try to do this. My only concern is that I need to repeat this same command for 5 other types of files, so there will be a lot of extra batch files. I would like to contain it within this one if possible. Thank you.

Comment: `for %a in (*.txt *.doc *.rtf) do @echo %a`

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like

```dos
set "RRIPPATH=x:\somewhere"
set "OUTPUT=y:\Same\OR\AnotherPlace"
set "INPUT_FILES=z:\Where\Files\are"

pushd "%RRIPPATH%"
for %%a in ("%INPUT_FILES%\*NTUSER.DAT") do (
    >> "%OUTPUT%\LiveResponseData\%%~nxa.txt" (
        perl rip.pl -r "%%~fa" -f ntuser
    )
)
popd
```